# What interpreted language can i leverage for debugging?

Tags: interpreted-language

I spoke about developing a programming language. Instead of making it compiled i am considering making it interpreted. So what i like to do is parse the syntax myself, build the AST and output source in an existing scripting language.

The thing i'd like to know is what interpreted language can i leverage for debugging? I'd like a call stack, file/source name and line #, to modify variables on the fly, etc.

What IDE must i use? i like visual studios but i presume it has no support for any interpreted languages

Answer (score 0):

You should use Eclipse to do what you want. There is a lot of any interpreted language supports and you can easily debug with the Debug Perspective.

The advantage of the Python language is that all is open-source. Indeed, there is no obfuscation and you can watch the source code without any problem.